# what are differences bewteen these DataStax Cassandra services' applications

Tags: cassandra, windows-services, datastax, opscenter

when opening `windows services`, three `DataStax services` appear in there:

[image: the services]

When I stop `DataStax OpsCenter Agent`, `DataStax Cassandra Community Server` stops automatically. I read the [definition](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/install/installingAgents.html) of `DataStax OpsCenter Agent` that `OpsCenter` attempts to automatically install the `agents` on the nodes in the newly added cluster. 
I want to know what the differences of these three `DataStax` services?What are their unique applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastax Cassandra Community Server is the cassandra daemon

Datstax Opscenter Community is almost certainly Datastax's web based Cassandra cluster manager

Datastax Opscenter Agent is the agent that runs on each cassandra node to feed metrics/data back to Datastax Opscenter Community. Opscenter will install an agent on each cassandra server in the cluster, and that agent must be running for opscenter to work properly.

If stopping the agent also stops Opscenter or Cassandra, that seems like a bug.